# dijit.form.Select onChange() running on page load

Tags: select, dojo, onchange

I'm new to Dojo and have a problem with my onChange() event, it runs when the page loads and not when the value in the Select box is changed.  Here's my code, its all in the body section section of the page.  Thanks for your help.

```
<div id="supportCentersListBox" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Select"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.Select");      

    function populateSupportCenters() {
        var supportCenters = new dijit.form.Select({
        maxHeight:"300",
            id: "supportCenters",
            onChange: changeTest(),
            store: new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore( { url: "some url address here" })
        }, 'supportCentersListBox');
    }

    function changeTest() {
        alert("Changed");
    }

    populateSupportCenters();
</script>
```

Comment: what value is it being changed to?  the `onChange` event will be passed the value that is being changed to. I suspect that when the store is finally loaded the select's value changes from null to the first item in the store or something like that.

Comment: BuffaloBubbalo, Thanks for the reply... What I ultimately want to do is when the user selects a new value in the Select box, pass that value to another function and do something with it, in this case pass it to changeTest().  I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your code so that the onChange is not a function `call` but instead a function pointer/reference

You have this 'problem':

1. `<div id="supportCentersListBox" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Select">` DOM renders (data-dojo-type is for parseOnLoad (dojo.parser) only, dont need it since youre creating it yourself
2. you instantiate a store
3. you instantiate a Select and render in supportCentersListBox - with `store` set, that fetches the `url`
4. fetch completes and `Select` is filled in
5. the item which has attribute `selected:true` or the first in index is set as value
6. `onChange` fires

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that information was very helpful.  I also found this tutorial to be helpful as well.

http://blog.jasonhoule.com/tag/filteringselect/